# Boarding pass not received immediately after paying and confirming booking with Ryanair

Tags: tickets, paperwork, ryanair

I booked and got confirmed booking for flight with Ryanair which should happen in 4 days via Skyscanner. Ryanair sent me tavel itinerary and confirmed booking, which is visible both on their web site and in phone app, but they never sent me a boarding pass. It is not in app, not on web, nowhere.

I am trying to contact them for days through contact numbers worldwide, but nobody picks up the phone. Their bot doesn't understand any of my questions. What can I do? Flight should happen on August 17th, early in morning, now is August 13th... I need time to print board and be sure that it will be there in app or in my e-mail before I travel in another country just to fly from there to third country.

I am extremely frustrated. What can I do? They don't offer absolutely NONE e-mail contatcs, phone contracts are useless....

Comment: I don't know about Ryanair (but I suspect they are like most other airlines), but with all airlines I've heard of, you only get your boarding pass when checking in, and that is normally not possible 4 days in advance (normally it becomes possible 24-48 hours before the flight - dependant on the airline and destination).  A confirmed booking is about what you can expect at the moment.

Comment: Thank you. I have different experience, but this is first time that I will be flying wiht Ryanair. Every time I booked a ticket and booking was comfirmed, I could see a boarding pass with code in app or on web site of flying company. How can I be sure that a boarding pass will EVER be there? Thanks for answer, I hope that you are right....

Comment: Other than the boarding pass, do you actually see the flight in your bookings on the website?

Comment: You need to check in before you receive a boarding pass. Have you completed online check in yet?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what airline were you flying with when you got your boarding pass right away? I used to take about a hundred flights a year (back when flying was still a thing) but I've literally never received a boarding pass before (online or in-person) check-in.

Comment: @TooTea That's now common with European low-cost carriers. For example, Easyjet routinely issues the boarding pass automatically if you are booking less than 30 days in advance (earlier, you did have to explicitely check-in but that was already possible only 30 days before the flight).

Comment: @Relaxed Oh, I used to fly Easyjet a lot, but they still had "online check-in" as a formally separate process (that you were invited to do right away after booking, but it still required filling in your contact data and clicking "Yes, I want to check in"). Is that now completely folded into the booking process?

Comment: @TooTea The word "check-in" might be there somewhere and you do have one or two extra clicks to acknowledge carry-on rules and the like so there is still in fact a separate check-in process but it's completely seamless and you get your boarding pass immediately upon booking with no obvious way to defer check-in.

Answer (score 25):

This is perfectly normal. You will receive your boarding pass* after you check in to your flight.

[Check-in for Ryanair flights opens](https://help.ryanair.com/hc/en-gb/articles/360017682977-Important-Check-in-Information):

- 60 days before the flight if you have a Flexi Plus ticket or have purchased a specific seat, or
- 24 hours before the scheduled departure time otherwise (48 hours if the booking was made before 28 January 2021)

*at least in normal times. Due to covid-related checks, at this time you may instead receive another document (containing the usual boarding pass information, but marked "this is not a boarding pass") and a set of instructions for how to collect the actual boarding pass.

Comment: You could add that the OP *should* have received the amadeus code (6 digit/letter) which is the unique code for their itinerary. This code can be used to check in, when it is open, at any terminal which does check in, at the airport or at any travel agents'.